# Node.js / Azure Event Hubs "TypeError: EventHubProducerClient is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to put together a very simple node script to send some data to Azure Event Hubs.
Here is my script (send.js):

```
const { EventHubProducerClient } = require("@azure/event-hubs");

// Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub.
const producer = new EventHubProducerClient("Endpoint=sb://auditblobevents.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=k9GhYMwABTBa6PuHKczIolE7FJeR0bOpQ+AEhEgMAY8=", "auditblobtopic");

// Create a JSON record.
const jsonRecord = {
  id: 1234567890,
  timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
  message: "This is a JSON record."
};

// Send the JSON record to the event hub.
 producer.send({ body: JSON.stringify(jsonRecord) });

// Close the producer client.
 producer.close();
```

When I run this command: "node send.js" I get this error:

```
TypeError: EventHubProducerClient is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/eugene.goldberg117/dev/node_eventhubs/send.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v19.4.0
```

What should I change to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm which @azure/event-hubs version is installed?

Also, refer to the [documentation website](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/event-hubs-javascript/) for detailed instructions on how to write and run a sample to send events.